# oracle drop table if doesn't exist (in one line)

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to do something on Oracle that is done on Sql Server like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM   dbo.Scores) DROP TABLE dbo.Scores
```

Note that i want to avoid the multi line pl sql since this can be repeated many times in a single script.

Initially wrote it as a proc, but then realized in Oracle the proc belongs to a schema and that schema would need elevated rights which is not desirable.

as plan B I am trying to execute output of a function call like this

```
execute immediate FN_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS('mySchema','myTable');
```

again my goal is to have a way to do this in one line. above should return a table drop statement, or some void type statement if table does not exist?

Comment: `execute immediate` is a PL/SQL statement; do you really mean the SQL\*Plus (and SQL Developer) `execute` statement, which is just a wrapper for an anonymous block? I'm not sure what you mean by 'execute output of function` - why not have the function (or, actually, procedure in this case) execute the drop dynamically if the table exists?

Comment: @AlexPoole because the executing proc would have a lot of permissions. i need it to use the context of whoever is executing the table drop so that permissions still work correctly based on user.

Comment: [Even if it's created with invoker's rights?](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/dr_ir.htm#DBSEG99925)

Comment: if this works the way i hope it does, it would be the right solution!

Comment: @AlexPoole is it possible to just tell the proc to use the invokers privileges anytime it is called?

Comment: The proc has to be created with invoker's rights (see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809). You can't change which it uses at runtime.

Comment: how can i tell it to use current_user rights when invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your function - or more properly, in this context, a procedure - with [invoker's rights](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/dr_ir.htm#DBSEG99925), which means that the commands in it will run as the calling user, with their privileges - rather than as the procedure owner. You wouldn't then need to pass in the schema.

```
create procedure drop_table_if_exists(p_table_name varchar2)
authid current_user
as
  e_does_not_exist exception;
  pragma exception_init(e_does_not_exist, -942);
begin
  execute immediate 'drop table ' || p_table_name;
exception
  when e_does_not_exist then
    null; -- could report if you want
end drop_table_if_exists;
/
```

When you can call it as:

```
exec drop_table_if_exists('my_table');
```

For example, if you create a table and then try to drop it twice, you don't see the exception form the second attempt:

```
create table my_table (id number);

Table MY_TABLE created.

exec drop_table_if_exists('my_table');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

exec drop_table_if_exists('my_table');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Your procedure could also query the data dictionary (`user_tables`) to see whether it exists, and then only drop it if it does, rather than try to drop and handle the exception.

You also need to be aware of case-sensitive table names and referential integrity which will need tables to be dropped in a specific order.

Comment: thanks so much! i was missing this: *authid current_user*
this is great, will solve many problems!

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle exception when there is no such table:

```
create or replace procedure drop_it(pv_name in varchar2)
is
begin
 execute immediate 'drop table schema.' || pv_name ||'  purge';
exception when others then null; end;
```

Comment: yeah that's what i'm hoping to avoid :) it's just so nasty having to do this 20x in a single release script and having to remember the exception catching syntax etc. i am hoping i could encapsulate these details in a proc or a function.

Comment: @SonicSoul - this *is* encapsulating all of that into a procedure, it's doing much the same as mine, but with definer's rights (by default) and a fixed schema, which isn't quite what you want. Also make sure you understand the implications of 'purge'.

Comment: thanks for spending the time to write this man! I had a proc but the only thing that stopped me from using it was permissions. Alex pointed me to *authid current_user* which actually solved the problem for me